# Issue with RxJs BehaviorSubject's subscriber not being notified of value change

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs5

I am trying to use a RxJS `BehaviorSubject` that contains a `boolean` representing whether or not a user is connected/logged in the application.

Here is the component that subscribes to the new `BehaviorSubject` value i.e. **`true`** when the user has authenticated:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CollapseDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import {PublicNavbarComponent} from './public.navbar.component';
import {PrivateNavbarComponent} from './private.navbar.component';
import {SessionService} from '../../session/session.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/components/navbar.component.html',
    providers: [SessionService],
    directives: [PublicNavbarComponent, PrivateNavbarComponent, CollapseDirective]
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private sessionService:SessionService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sessionService.authenticated$.subscribe({
            next: (value)=> this.isAuthenticated = value
        });
    }

    isAuthenticated:boolean = false;

    isCollapsed:boolean = true;
}
```

Here is the class/service containing the `BehaviorSubject`:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Credentials} from '../shared/models/credentials.model';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

    authenticated$:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    currentUserAccount;

    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    signin(credentials:Credentials) {
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        this.http.post('/api/signin', 'username=' + credentials.username + '&password=' + credentials.password, options)
            .subscribe(response=>
                this.setPersonalInfo(response.headers.get('x-auth-token'))
            );
    }

    setPersonalInfo(sessionToken) {
        localStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true');
        localStorage.setItem('sessionToken', sessionToken);
        this.authenticated$.next(true);//next() from false to true
        this.http.get('/api/utils/current-useraccount')
            .subscribe(param => this.currentUserAccount = param);
    }
}
```

However this does not have the expected behavior: it seems that `authenticated$` from session service is only true within `setPersonalInfo` function and `isAuthenticated` from `NavbarComponent` isn't notified at all when `this.authenticated$.next(true)` is invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you have multiple instances of `SessionService`. e.g. you provided it more than once and the instance that you call `signin` in is not the same instance as the one you injected in `NavbarComponent`.

It depends on your project design how you provide your services. Usually session services are singletons.
I recommend removing `providers: [SessionService],` from `NavbarComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually provide `SessionService` at bootstrap (and not with `providers: []`) to make sure you share **one global** `SessionService` instance throughout the entire app.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,
            [SessionService]);
```

Comment: I like `bootstrap()` as well because it makes it more obvious that the providers are supposed to be global but according to the style guide, global providers should not be added to `bootstrap()` but instead to the root component. There are no technical reasons for this. They just consider it more maintainable.