# RXJS service http call returns null after another call

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, components, observable

I have my services with http calls:

I initialize my component with nginit, then after i leave the view, go to the detail view, and call a post service, my component returns null and break the app, and i have to reload my page.

Is there any best practices for using observables in services and components?

I have tried to research multicast, bit i havent found anything related to my problem.

Service Call

```
getProducts() {
    this.headers = this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('id', 1)
      .set('active', '1')
      .set('token', 1);
    return this.http.get(this.env + 'Products.json', { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

I usually expect my response array like on the ngoninit, but instead gets null.

**Update**

Got it to work by declaring my services on the component decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deal-detail',
  templateUrl: './deal-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deal-detail.component.scss'],
  providers: [ AService, BService, CService ]
})
```

Comment: What does the network panel of the browser say was the response body for the request? Did the server send `null`?

Comment: How do you use the service in details? or where is it breaking? Please share some more code

Comment: Thank you all guys, i got it working, i will provide more details for anyone who had the same issue or if anyone has any input, will be appreciated still. Apparently i didnt initialized my services on the component decorator using the 'providers'.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by providing my components with the providers attribute, i was referenced by: [issue-with-rxjs-behaviorsubjects-subscriber-not-being-notified-of-value-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150891/issue-with-rxjs-behaviorsubjects-subscriber-not-being-notified-of-value-change)

Apparently Angular reads the services as singletons.